# C++: 'expected unqualified-id before '(' token' Pointer to Member Functions in a Class

Tags: c++, oop, arduino, arduino-esp8266

So I'm trying to call a member function pointer in the code below, using a map of member function pointers of `typedef void (CommandHandler::*pfunc)(std::vector<String>&)`
However, I'm having issues getting the syntax to work because I get the following error:
expected unqualified-id before '(' token

Note that this is Arduino, and the ArduinoSTL supports most STL calls.

This line fails, and commenting out this line results in code that indeed compiles.

```
((this).(*(this.cmd_func)))(parses);
```

I've tried different syntaxes that I've seen online, eg https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members. 
Even in that syntax it resulted in errors. (eg using the macro below still resulted in errors)

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with my typedef type and the compiler spitting out an error that doesn't make sense (immediately) when looking at the code. Can anyone help me understand why this code fails? Thanks!

Full file below

```
#include <ArduinoSTL.h>
#include<map>
#include <vector>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#define LED_PIN    4
#define LED_COUNT 12
#define MY_ROLE 0
//#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember)) //This call doesn't work in Arduino

#define X_ADDR 0
#define Y_ADDR 1
#define MY_ROLE 2

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

class CommandHandler{
  typedef void (CommandHandler::*pfunc)(std::vector<String>&);

  CommandHandler::CommandHandler(){
    x = EEPROM.read(X_ADDR);
    y = EEPROM.read(Y_ADDR);
    role_id = MY_ROLE;
    init_commands_with_args();
  }
  CommandHandler::CommandHandler(int x, int y, int role_id){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->role_id = role_id;
    init_commands_with_args();
  }
  public:
    int x, y, role_id;
    std::map<String, pfunc> commandsTable; 
    void set_red(){show_led_int(255,0,0);}
    void set_green(){show_led_int(0,255,0);}
    void set_blue(){show_led_int(0,0,255);}
    void set_purple(){show_led_int(255, 0, 255);}
    void set_yellow(){show_led_int(255, 255, 0);}
    void set_cyan(){show_led_int(0,255,255);}
    void set_white(){show_led_int(255,255,255);}
    void set_none(){show_led_int(0,0,0);}

    void init_commands_with_args(){
      commandsTable["a"] = &show_led;
      //commandsTable["b"] = &blink_color;
      //commandsTable["c"] = &theaterChase;
      //commandsTable["d"] = &rainbow;
      //commandsTable["e"] = &theaterChaseRainbow;
      return;
    }

    void handle_command(std::string input, std::string delimiter = "/"){
      if (input.size() == 1){
        switch(input[0]){
          case 'R':
            CommandHandler::set_red();
          case 'B':
            CommandHandler::set_blue();
          case 'G':
            CommandHandler::set_green();
          case 'W':
            CommandHandler::set_white();
          case 'P':
            CommandHandler::set_purple();
          case 'C':
            CommandHandler::set_cyan();
          case 'Y':
            CommandHandler::set_yellow();
          case 'N':
            CommandHandler::set_none();
          }
        }
        else{
          std::vector<String> parses; // 10 maximum args
          size_t pos = 0; size_t i = 0;
          String token;
          //std::string tokens = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
          while ((pos = input.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
              token = String(input.substr(0, pos).c_str());
              //std::cout << token << std::endl;
              parses.push_back(token);
              input.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
              i++;
          }
          //Parses is now an array of strings.
          pfunc cmd_func = commandsTable[parses[0]];
          parses.erase(parses.begin());
          ((this).(*(this.cmd_func)))(parses); //This line fails no matter what I try to do. //Expected unqualified-id before '(' token
          //I want to call the function of this instance that is in commandsTable, with arguments defined in the vector parses.
          //The first element of the vector which is later erased is the function in commandsTable that is mapped
          //Other elements are arguments in the string.
        }
    }



    void blink(){
      delay(0.5*role_id);
      this->show_led_int(255, 255, 255);
      delay(0.5);
      this->show_led_int(0, 0, 0);
    }
    //void blink_color(int r, int b, int g){
    void blink_color(std::vector<String> & input){
      int r = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();
      int b = String(input[1].c_str()).toInt();
      int g = String(input[2].c_str()).toInt();  
      uint32_t mycolor = strip.Color(r, b, g);
      delay(0.5*role_id);
      this->show_led_int(r, b, g);
      delay(0.5);
      this->show_led_int(0, 0, 0);
    }
    //void show_led(int r, int b, int g){
    void show_led(std::vector<String> & input){
      int r = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();
      int b = String(input[1].c_str()).toInt();
      int g = String(input[2].c_str()).toInt();  
      uint32_t mycolor = strip.Color(r, b, g);
      strip.setPixelColor(0, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(1, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(2, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(3, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(4, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(5, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(6, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(7, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(8, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(9, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(10, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(11, mycolor);
      strip.show();
    }
   void show_led_int(int r, int b, int g){
      uint32_t mycolor = strip.Color(r, b, g);
      strip.setPixelColor(0, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(1, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(2, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(3, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(4, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(5, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(6, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(7, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(8, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(9, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(10, mycolor);
      strip.setPixelColor(11, mycolor);
      strip.show();
    }
    //void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {
    void colorWipe(std::vector<String> & input){
      uint32_t color = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();;
      int wait = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();;
      for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { // For each pixel in strip...
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color);         //  Set pixel's color (in RAM)
        strip.show();                          //  Update strip to match
        delay(wait);                           //  Pause for a moment
      }
    }
    //void theaterChase(uint32_t color, int wait) {
    void theaterChase(std::vector<String> & input){
      uint32_t color = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();
      int wait = String(input[1].c_str()).toInt();
      for(int a=0; a<10; a++) {  // Repeat 10 times...
      for(int b=0; b<3; b++) { //  'b' counts from 0 to 2...
        strip.clear();         //   Set all pixels in RAM to 0 (off)
        // 'c' counts up from 'b' to end of strip in steps of 3...
        for(int c=b; c<strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color); // Set pixel 'c' to value 'color'
        }
        strip.show(); // Update strip with new contents
        delay(wait);  // Pause for a moment
      }
      }
    }

    // Rainbow cycle along whole strip. Pass delay time (in ms) between frames.
    //void rainbow(int wait) {
    void rainbow(std::vector<String> & input){
      int wait = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();
      for(long firstPixelHue = 0; firstPixelHue < 5*65536; firstPixelHue += 256) {
      for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { // For each pixel in strip...
        // Offset pixel hue by an amount to make one full revolution of the
        // color wheel (range of 65536) along the length of the strip
        // (strip.numPixels() steps):
        int pixelHue = firstPixelHue + (i * 65536L / strip.numPixels());
        // strip.ColorHSV() can take 1 or 3 arguments: a hue (0 to 65535) or
        // optionally add saturation and value (brightness) (each 0 to 255).
        // Here we're using just the single-argument hue variant. The result
        // is passed through strip.gamma32() to provide 'truer' colors
        // before assigning to each pixel:
        strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(pixelHue)));
      }
      strip.show(); // Update strip with new contents
      delay(wait);  // Pause for a moment
      }
    }

    // Rainbow-enhanced theater marquee. Pass delay time (in ms) between frames.
    //void theaterChaseRainbow(int wait) {
    static void theaterChaseRainbow(std::vector<String> & input){
      int wait = String(input[0].c_str()).toInt();
      int firstPixelHue = 0;     // First pixel starts at red (hue 0)
      for(int a=0; a<30; a++) {  // Repeat 30 times...
      for(int b=0; b<3; b++) { //  'b' counts from 0 to 2...
        strip.clear();         //   Set all pixels in RAM to 0 (off)
        // 'c' counts up from 'b' to end of strip in increments of 3...
        for(int c=b; c<strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {
        // hue of pixel 'c' is offset by an amount to make one full
        // revolution of the color wheel (range 65536) along the length
        // of the strip (strip.numPixels() steps):
        int      hue   = firstPixelHue + c * 65536L / strip.numPixels();
        uint32_t color = strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(hue)); // hue -> RGB
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color); // Set pixel 'c' to value 'color'
        }
        strip.show();                // Update strip with new contents
        delay(wait);                 // Pause for a moment
        firstPixelHue += 65536 / 90; // One cycle of color wheel over 90 frames
      }
    }
  }
    void updateRole(std::vector<String> & input){
      this->role_id = input[0].toInt();
    }
    void updateLoc(std::vector<String> & input){
      this->x = input[0].toInt();
      this->y = input[1].toInt();
      EEPROM.write(X_ADDR, this->x);
      EEPROM.write(Y_ADDR, this->y);
    }
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: The line with  (this). ", know that 'this' is a reserved word and is always a pointer.  So if you might try something with ' this-> ' in place of ' this. ', though I don't know about your parenthesis.

Comment: Also, your switch statement is missing `break`s.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't catch the switch statement break. Woops!

Answer (score 0):

Calling a pointer-to-member can get a little complicated looking.  Since `this` is a pointer, and `CALL_MEMBER_FN` expects a reference, you'd use the macro as

```
CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this, this->cmd_func)(parses);
```

Or, without the macro,

```
(this->*(this->cmd_func))(parses);
```

Comment: I'm crossposting, but I was able to solve it. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=663750.0 
Essentially, what was needed was that the cmd_func variable had to be declared within my class and not in my handle_command function. Do you (or anyone) understand why it needs to be declared within the class itself?

Comment: @user150766 I was mostly looking at what you posted at the start of your question and didn't look thru all of that code.  The `cmd_func` variable does not have to be a member, but the way the you were trying it was as a member.  You reference it like any other variable.  With it declared within the function, you'd just use `CALL_MEMBER_FN(*thiis, cmd_func)(parses);`.